# Rewriting an expression in order to avoid cancellation

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, numerical-methods

I've trying to "fix" this expression to avoid cancellation:

$$
\frac{1-(\cos(x))^3}{x^2}.
$$

Common sense is suggesting me to change that ugly cosine for a sine, so the values near to 0 won't suffer cancellation, but I've been trying different substitutions in the numerator and I wasn't able to completely remove the cosine.

I'd appreciate any suggestion or a hint.

Thank you for the time.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for trigonometric identities, or any method would do to compute the limit at $0$? (e.g., Taylor, etc.)

Comment: @ClementC. I'm looking for a way to avoid cancellation for every value, not only at 0 (otherwise taylor should work fine for this problem).

Comment: There will be values for which it does cancel, though, no matter what you do. Evaluate the expression at $2\pi n$, for any $n \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1-\cos^3 x}{x^2} = \frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{x^2}\cdot\left(1+\cos x+\cos^2 x\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{\sin(x/2)}{x/2}\right)^2\cdot \left(1+\cos x+\cos^2 x\right)$$

and now no factor is troublesome in a neighborhood of zero, since:
$$ \frac{\sin z}{z}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} $$
is an entire function.

Comment: From the comment above, it's unclear to me whether the OP wanted to avoid cancellation "on a neighborhood of $0$" (for which showing a non-zero limit at $0$ is enough), or everywhere (which is not possible). Cf. *"I'm looking for a way to avoid cancellation for every value, not only at 0 ".*

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply extending continuously the function at $x=0$ ? Thanks to l'Hospital's rule, we have $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-(\cos(x))^3}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{3\cos^2(x)\sin(x)}{2x}=\frac{3}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

To "remove" the cancellation *at $0$*, one can use any of the "usual suspects" (basic limits, L'Hôpital, you name it; I would go for Taylor expansions, to low order). For instance, from $\cos u  = 1- \frac{u^2}{2} + o(u^2)$ and $(1+u)^3 = 1+3u+o(u)$ at $0$, you get
$$
\frac{1-\cos^3 x}{x^2} = \frac{1-(1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2))^3}{x^2} =  \frac{1-(1-\frac{3x^2}{2}+o(x^2))}{x^2}=  \frac{3}{2}+o(1)
$$
when $x\to 0$.

However, besides $0$ your expression **will** cancel at any $x=2\pi n$, for $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, no matter what transformations you do. (And it is easy to see these are the only points.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compute the value of the expression when $x$ is very close to $0$, just use Taylor series of $\cos(x)$ to get $$\frac{1-\cos^3(x)}{x^2}=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{7 x^2}{8}+\frac{61 x^4}{240}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approched.

For example, if $x=10^{-8}$, the above formula would give $$\frac{35999999999999997900000000000000061}{24000000000000000000000000000000000}\approx 1.499999999999999912500000$$ which is the value you would obtain using illimited precision.